# Need help on Codeigniter gchart help usage

Tags: php, codeigniter, syntax-error, gchart

I followed the wiki artichle (http://codeigniter.com/wiki/gchart/revision/5312/) to practice google chart in my CI 2.0. 
But it doesn't work.

controller file: ci\application\helpers\mytest.php

```
$this->load->helper( 'gchart' );
$this->load->view('my_test');
```

view file: ci\application\helpers\my_test.php

```
$encoded_data = extendedencode(array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) &maxvalue;);
echo <<< EOS
     <img src="
        http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?
            cht=lc
            &chs=250x250
            &chd;:e{$encoded}
        "
        alt="line graph of some example data" />
EOS;
```

help file: ci\application\helpers\gchart_helper.php

```
// I do copied all the source code from the wiki url link above.
```

When I try to charted by CI.
It showed error as this,
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\ci\application\views\my_test.php on line 54**

Any thing wrong on my operation?
I compared the extendedencode() from gchart_helper.php

```
function extendedencode($data, &$maxvalue='notspecified')
```

and extendedencode() from my_test.php

```
$encoded_data = extendedencode(array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) &maxvalue;);
```

Then I updated the extendedencode() line to this in my_test.php view file,

```
$encoded_data = extendedencode(array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), &maxvalue);
```

And try again, but still get this error below.

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\ci\application\views\my_test.php on line 54**

Any help or comments are great appreciated.

[updated]

```
When I use the formated below, 

$encoded_data = extendedencode(array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) &maxvalue);

showed another four error message.



Events List

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Use of undefined constant maxvalue - assumed 'maxvalue'

Filename: views/my_test.php

Line Number: 54

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: max() [function.max]: When only one parameter is given, it must be an array

Filename: helpers/gchart_helper.php

Line Number: 49

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Division by zero

Filename: helpers/gchart_helper.php

Line Number: 55

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: encoded

Filename: views/my_test.php

Line Number: 61
```

**[Updated against Frank's suggestion]**

There are still two errors occurred below,

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 64

Filename: helpers/gchart_helper.php

Line Number: 65  // code line: $ret .= $grid[$x].$grid[$y];


A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: encoded

Filename: views/my_test.php

Line Number: 61 // code line: &chd;:e{$encoded}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alex's answer isn't syntactically correct.  Try:

```
$encoded_data = extendedencode(array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), $maxvalue);
```

The & in the function documentation just tells you that your variable will be used by reference.  You shouldn't (and in fact cannot) include the & when you call the function.  In older versions of PHP, there was a feature called call-time pass by reference, in which you'd use syntax like that, but it's disallowed in recent versions.

Edit:

Regarding one of the additional errors you've listed: as the error says, there's no `$encoded` var in the code you've shown us.  Try replacing `&chd;:e{$encoded}` with `&chd;:e{$encoded_data}` -- I'm guessing that might be what you intended.

A sloppy method of silencing the final error would be to replace `$ret .= $grid[$x].$grid[$y];` with `$ret .= @$grid[$x].@$grid[$y];`.  Without additional context for the code in play there, it's hard to say what the actual root issue is there.

Comment: yeah, reference usage and it's disallowed in recent version.

Comment: Hi Frank, I updated my post again based on your suggestion. And there are still two errors. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bad semi colon on this line:

```
$encoded_data = extendedencode(array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) &maxvalue;);
```

right after `&maxvalue`.

Try taking it out?

Comment: That seems like a different error than originally posted. If this cleared the first error you had successfully, please mark it as accepted and ask a new question for your new issue. Thanks!

Comment: Alex: what you've provided isn't valid PHP, and as such, isn't a helpful answer.

Comment: That line was from his original posting, he's since edited it. Please don't downvote, I was fixing the same problem as you (check the edit history)

Comment: Even with the semicolon taken out, there are still 2 syntax errors on that line that you didn't mention.